# Передача данных с JS в шаблон Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с реализацией такой идеи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]По нажатию на этаж дома с помощью JS определяется цифра, которая отвечает за номер этажа и передается в другой блок div в span с классом 'num-floor', который скрыт до нажатия на любой из этажей или на кнопку в нижнем правом углу

```js
function SetCounterToNumFloor()
{
    document.querySelector(".num-floor").textContent = counter.textContent
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так вот, проблема в том, что чтобы отобразить тут какие квартиры заняты, а какие нет, мне нужно проверить данные из БД, которые получены в шаблоне через views.py в таком виде (данные за все 179 квартир на всех этажах):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каким образом я могу получить номер этажа, который определен в JS, чтобы отсеять данные с БД и применить другой стиль к тексту справа, соответственно к полученным данным?
Предлагайте Ваши решения или как можно это сделать иначе, буду всем безумно благодарен, ибо только учусь и нуждаюсь в Вашей помощи
Подробнее ознакомиться можно по ссылке:

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)

```js
const $map = document.querySelector(`map`);

$map.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.alt);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

Можете также использовать [Mapper.js](https://www.resdal.org/educacion/mapas/mapper/mapper/#).

Comment: Можно какие-то комментарии к этому коду? Ибо у меня все основано на path и отслеживание нажатия на них. И все это одна страница сайта

Comment: @VladimirMaksymchuk исправил ответ.